# What is this substance on board?

Tags: transistors, capacitor

So I’m trying to fix my blu-ray player and there are two spots where this beige stuff is. Is this there intentionally, or is this the result of some malfunction?

Could someone please explain what it is and why it happened? 
Thanks
[image: Image of substance]

[image: Second image of substance]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's intentional. It's glue (of some sort) to keep parts steady and not break from vibrations when shipping or handling the unit.

Comment: Note that the green object in the second image (NTC1, a temperature sensor) appears to be socketed.  Not sure why the diode (DR1201) in the first image is glued; anyone want to venture a guess?

Comment: @AlexHajnal The diode seems to elevated, possibly due to a heat dissipation requirement from the extra length of the leads? Vibration could cause the leads to break, or they could be bent and contact the TO-220 device (which would probably fry something)

Comment: @Adam Yeah, it does seem high current.  I was thinking it might also be added strain relief on a glass package (though all diodes that large that I've seen haven't used glass).

Comment: Seems somewhat silly - diode likely placed higher to reduce thermal resistance, only to then get coated with insulating gunk. (Perhaps the impact of longer leads is more significant?)