# What is this translucent heat-resistant insulation?

Tags: identification, insulation

On the picture from [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/416792/what-is-this-substance-on-board), what is the translucent insulation on the transformer center-tap made from? It looks like polyethylene, but it obviously isn't because PE would melt at soldering temperatures.

[image]

Comment: Some kind of silicone rubber? can PTFE be made translucent with additives to lower its density? Interesting question!

Answer (score 6):

That looks very much like PTFE tubing. The thin-walled tubing tends to be translucent, but the degree of translucency also varies by manufacturer and even batch.

PTFE can operate up to 260°C continuously. Transformer tails like this are typically tinned onto the bobbin pins by solder-pot dipping, we use 255°C for our lead-free solder pots and the sleeving does not directly touch molten solder which leaves enough margin.
As well as soldering you have to also remember that the maximum internal temperature of these type of high-frequency transformers can exceed 100°C which will limit your sleeving material choice too.